# Parsing a field that only some object contains

Tags: jquery, xml

```
<collection>
    <personRepresentaion>
        <theId>1</theId>
        <name>John</name>
        <height>10</height>
        <width>12</width>
        <relationships>
            <inputId>1324</inputId>
            <outputId>1325</outputId>
        </relationships>
    </personRepresentaion>
    <personRepresentaion>
        <theId>2</theId>
        <name>Bill</name>
        <height>10</height>
        <width>12</width>
    </personRepresentaion>
    <personRepresentaion>
        <theId>3</theId>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <height>10</height>
        <width>12</width>
        <relationships>
            <inputId>1324</inputId>
            <outputId>1325</outputId>
        </relationships>
    </personRepresentaion>
</collection>
```

CurrentlyI am this XML file, and I want to parse out the field < outputId >, so I can use my function connectId(source, destination) to connect those 2 objects.

The problem is that I am using a for loop like the following to display them on my page:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("personRepresentaion");

for(i=0;i<x.length;i++) { 
connectId(x[i].getElementsByTagName("theId")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
x[i].getElementsByTagName("relationships")[0].getElementsByTagName("outputId")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

But `Bill` in the XML does not have the field `< relationships >`, so the loop just stops and exits when it gets to Bill.

I need to first find only the persons that HAS < relationships > field, then use a for loop, then call connectId() for those objects, how do I achieve this?

Comment: your xml and the javascript are not matching - what is `beanRepresentation`, `beanRepId` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
$xml.find('personRepresentaion').has('outputId').has('inputId').each(function () {
    var $br = $(this);
    connectId($br.find('theId').text(), $br.find('outputId').text());
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YqqH6/)